# image loader does not loading image

Tags: android, image

hi I have image loader class that load image from the web and caching on phone the problem is
on phone doesn't have sd card(External Memory) image not loaded from the web how can I fix it
here is image loader class code

```
 public class ImageLoader {

  final int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_thumbnail;
  MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
  FileCache fileCache;
  ExecutorService executorService;
  private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());

  public ImageLoader(Context context) {
  fileCache = new FileCache(context);
  executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
  }

  public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
  imageViews.put(imageView, url);
  Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
  if (bitmap != null)
  imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  else {
  queuePhoto(url, imageView);
  imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
  }
  }

  private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
  PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
  executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
  }

  private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
  File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

  //from SD cache
  Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
  if (b != null)
  return b;

  //from web
  try {
  Bitmap bitmap = null;
  URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
  conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
  conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
  conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
  InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
  OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
  Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
  os.close();
  bitmap = decodeFile(f);
  return bitmap;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
  return null;
  }
  }

  //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
  private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
  try {
  //decode image size
  BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

  //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
  final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 150;
  int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
  int scale = 1;
  while (true) {
  if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
  break;
  width_tmp /= 2;
  height_tmp /= 2;
  scale *= 2;
  }

  //decode with inSampleSize
  BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  o2.inSampleSize = scale;
  return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  }
  return null;
  }

  boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
  String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
  if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
  return true;
  return false;
  }

  public void clearCache() {
  memoryCache.clear();
  fileCache.clear();
  }

  //Task for the queue
  private class PhotoToLoad {
  public String url;
  public ImageView imageView;

  public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
  url = u;
  imageView = i;
  }
  }

  class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
  PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

  PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
  this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
  }

  public void run() {
  if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
  return;
  Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
  memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
  if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
  return;
  BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
  Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
  a.runOnUiThread(bd);
  }
  }

  //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
  class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
  Bitmap bitmap;
  PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

  public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
  bitmap = b;
  photoToLoad = p;
  }

  public void run() {
  if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
  return;
  if (bitmap != null) {
  photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

  }//else
  // photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
  }
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use LRU Cache and its pretty easy to setup.

```
final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

// Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
   @Override
   protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
      // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than number of items.
      return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
   }
};
public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return mMemoryCache.get(key);
}
```

Reference - https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

I would strong suggest using one of the image library like picasso or glide or Network library like Volley instead of writing your own, i have use volley with LRU cache and works well.

Comment: thank you but i want to edit my code not using new library